# Displaying 200 Distinct prime numbers from 0 to 10000

Tags: java, integer

I've been trying a code for printing 200 prime numbers whose reverse is also a prime number and the number must not be a palindrome. I've set a limit of 10000 numbers to check assuming there would be about 200 such primes within it. But I get an Array Out Of Bound exception in the 51'st line. Can anybody clear this out for me?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
class Functions
{
    int prime(int x)
    {
        int z=0;
        for(int i=2;i<x;i++)
        {
            if(x%i==0) z=1;
        }
        if(z==1) return 0;
        else return 1;
    }

    int reverse(int x)
    {
        int rev=0;
        while(x!=0)
        { rev=rev*10; rev=rev+x%10; x=x/10; }
        return rev;
    }
    int find(int x,int y[])
    {
        for(int g=0;y[g]!=0;g++)
        {
            if(x==y[g]) return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}       

class Distinctp
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        Functions S=new Functions();
        int i;
        int a[]=new int[200];
        for(i=1;i<10000;i++)
        {
            if(S.prime(i)==1 && S.prime(S.reverse(i))==1)
            {
                if(i!=S.reverse(i))
                {
                    if(S.find(S.reverse(i),a)==0)
                    {
                        for(int k=0;k<199;k++)
                        {
                             if(a[k]==0) //For assigning value in the last space of the array
                            { a[k]=i; a[k+1]=0; }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<200;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }   
    }
}
```

I've cleared the Exception but I'm still not getting a proper output. When I run this,only the number 13 is getting printed repeatedly. Please help me out.

Comment: What's the 51st line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code would cause [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) when `k==199`, since `a[k+1]` would be `a[200]`, which is out of bounds.

```
        for(int k=0;k<200;k++)
        {
             if(a[k]==0) //For assigning value in the last space of the array
             { 
                 a[k]=i;
                 a[k+1]=0;
             }
        }
```

I don't see the purpose of `a[k+1]=0;`

Answer (score 0):

[Eran pointed out the issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25341415/3622940)

To solve it, you have to limit the upper boundary of the `for` loop like this:

```
for(int k = 0; k < 199; k++) {
     if(a[k] == 0) { 
         a[k]     = i;
         a[k + 1] = 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: Off topic: Use your debugger in your IDE.